# Symfony2 LiipFunctionalTestBundle overriding @validator service

Tags: php, symfony, liipfunctionaltestbundle

I am trying to inject @validator into my service but LiipFunctionalTestBundle is overriding that service when it gets injected.

```
admin.image_service:
    class: AdminBundle\Service\ImageService
    arguments: ["@validator", "@doctrine.orm.admin_entity_manager", "@image_storage_filesystem"]
```

Which results in the error

> must be an instance of Symfony\Component\Validator\Validator\RecursiveValidator, instance of Liip\FunctionalTestBundle\Validator\DataCollectingValidator given

running **php bin/console debug:container** results in

> liip_functional_test.validator:                                          Liip\FunctionalTestBundle\Validator\DataCollectingValidator
>
> validator:                                                              alias for "liip_functional_test.validator"

Is there a way to get around this over than remove liip and refactor all of my tests?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Your service you should typehint `Interface` not exact class.

Instdead `Symfony\Component\Validator\Validator\RecursiveValidator` use `Symfony\Component\Validator\Validator\ValidatorInterface` - which is implemented by both classes (Symfony and Liip).

Comment: Thanks, this saved me from having to upgrade everything.