# Symfony is not loading the correct validation service

Tags: php, symfony, validation, containers

I'm using Symfony framework 3.4. Currently i'm working on a validation method, but suddenly Symfony validation stopped working, and then all of my validations stopped working, then i run:

```
php bin/console debug:container
```

And i've got the following output for the validator service:

```
 Service ID                             ClassName                         
  validator              alias for "liip_functional_test.validator"
```

I have the following questions:
Is this the correct class name for the validator service?
What could i have done wrong?

My entire code is this:

```
namespace AppBundle\DataTransfer;

use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

class ProductFromApi
{

   /**
     * @Assert\IsTrue(message="Testing the validator")
     */
    public function isTestCorrect() : Bool
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: I was really puzzled by this override, but after a quick search, I've found out the similar SO question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35876322/symfony2-liipfunctionaltestbundle-overriding-validator-service

Comment: Yes, but the problem is that even after i solved the overriding problem the validator still doesn't work. When i run: php bin/console debug:container validator i got the same result as in the answer by: Cameron Hurd

Comment: I'm not using the validator service directly, i'm using the form->isValid(), and this form should be using the validator service.

Comment: Could you share a bit more of your config? Maybe `service.yml`, and excerpts from `config.yml` you think might be relevant? If the methods in the controller have anything out of the ordinary, it may help to see that, too!

Comment: Hi, i stopped docker and did docker-compose up again, and now it's working which is weird because i have done: php bin/console cache:clear before. Thank you everyone.

Answer (score 1):

It does look like the service "`validator`" is an alias for something other than the default symfony validator, doesn't it? (Specifically "`liip_functional_test.validator`")

When I run `php bin/console debug:container validator` on a Symfony project which I know doesn't have that liip bundle that you've got above, here's what it returns for me:

```
Information for Service "debug.validator"
=========================================

 ---------------- ----------------------------------------------------------
  Option           Value
 ---------------- ----------------------------------------------------------
  Service ID       debug.validator
  Class            Symfony\Component\Validator\Validator\TraceableValidator
  Tags             kernel.reset (method: reset)
  Public           no
  Synthetic        no
  Lazy             no
  Shared           yes
  Abstract         no
  Autowired        no
  Autoconfigured   no
 ---------------- ----------------------------------------------------------
```

Maybe you want to refer to it as "`debug.validator`" if you're getting the service out of the DI container by name.

That said you probably shouldn't be calling the validator in that way.

You've got the following in your `config.yml`, yeah?

```
framework:
    validation: { enable_annotations: true }
```

Comment: Yes, i have this YAML on my config.yml. I removed the liip_functional_test.validator bundle from my AppKernel, and then i've got the same output as you did, but the validator is not working.